# Eight is Enough

Tags: pattern, knowledge

My wife and I are expecting our 8th child very soon. she is obsessed with patterns and named our first six children (all girls). In order, they are named for:

1. A super-villainess whose alter ego is the wife of an Advertising Executive.
2. An air freshener.
3. A blue-haired woman who needs to clear her throat and get checked for jaundice.
4. A petulant municipal worker in a small Indiana town.
5. A bride-to-be that has had trouble with her maids and very recently has been mistaken for her younger sister, #6:
6. A suburban housewife who was very protective of hairy rodent wildlife.

Seeing this pattern and hoping to hurry things along, I named our seventh child (the only son so far) after:

7. A serial killer that likes hockey.

We're looking for potential names for our eighth (and *final*) child of as-of-yet unknown gender that will fit the pattern. Can you offer any viable choices?

<sub>(First answer that fully explains the pattern and gives a viable candidate name for #8 gets the win.)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. > Betty (Mad Men, played by *January* Jones)?
2. > … Febreze??
3. > Marge (The Simpsons)
4. > April (Parks and Rec)
5. > Lillian (Bridesmaids, played by *Maya* Rudolph)
6. > June (Leave It to Beaver)
7. > Jason, covering July August September October November

so we’re looking for a gender-neutral name

> related to December and a movie, TV show, or air freshener.

I’m having a lot of trouble with this one, but

> Dee fits in nicely after Jason. Relate to Gregory’s Girl, a calendar-y name for a film.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'll award the checkmark eventually. I wasn't specifically going for gender-neutral, just trying to give you freedom of choice with regard to gender as it's really hard to come up with a match.